# Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

i'm new to angualar js and ionic and during my development process i'm getting an error i have no idea of. it tells me a have a duplicated name in my script.

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $stateProvider
    .state('tabs',{ 
        url: '/tab',
        abstract:true,
        templateUrl:'templates/tabs.html'
    })

     .state('tabs.source',{
        url:'/source',
        views:{
        'list-source':{
        templateUrl:  'templates/source.html', 
        controller: 'feedsctrl'
        } 
        }
    })

.state('tabs.keeps',{
        url:'/keeps',
        views:{
        'list-keeps':{
        templateUrl:  'templates/keeps/keeps.html', 
        controller: 'keepsctrl'
        } 
        }
    })

.controller('keepsctrl',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){
$http.get('http://localhost/vivalooks/app_ion/templates/keeps/keeps.php').success(function(data){
       $scope.keeps=data ;
   });
}]);
```

keeps.php results

```
[{"fname":"Benjamin","lname":"Blay","pic":"4r4545.jpg ","fav_id":"4","wardrobe":null,"fav_total":"1"}]
```

below is the keep.html script

```
<ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
          <button class="icon ion-home button button-clear"></button>
      <h1 class="title">vivalooks</h1>
          <button class="icon ion-person button button-clear"></button>
      </ion-header-bar>

      <div class="bar bar-subheader item-input-inset bar-light">
      <label class="item-input-wrapper">
          <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
          <input type="search" placeholder="Search">

          </label>

      </div>
<ion-view>


<ion-content class="has-subheader">

    <ion-list class="list-inset" ng-repeat="items in keeps">
    <ion-item class="item-text-wrap">
       <div class="thumbnails_v"> <img ng-src="http://localhost/vivalooks/resize_image/vivalooks.php?image={{item.pic}}&new_width=300&new_height=300"">
           </div>
        <p>
        {{item.fname}} {{item.lname}}
        </p>

        </ion-item>

    </ion-list>

    </ion-content>

</ion-view>
```

Comment: Are you looping (ng-repeat) over $scope.keeps in the keeps template? If possible post the ng-repeat html and the structure of the keeps data. Basically it means you have duplicate items (according to angular) in the keeps data.

Comment: Show the html part of code.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan, i've editted the question and shown part of the html

Comment: It is just array of json. Show the template keeps.html

Comment: i've done the edit to the question again

Answer (score 0):

First thing that I notice is you're using wrong variable name in the repeat:

```
<ion-list class="list-inset" ng-repeat="items in keeps">
```

Your calling the value "items", and using "item" below. Change it to "item".

If this is not the problem, probably there's something wrong with the data. Did you check it? If not, just do console.log(data) inside the HTTP request.